# execute .reg from bat silently in windows 7 with UAC

Tags: windows, uac, windows-registry

I need to be able to push out registry fixes with AD logon script to Windows 7 systems with UAC enabled. So far I have had no luck accomplishing this using the standard method that worked in XP.

```
regedit.exe /s
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without turning UAC off?

Thanks for your kind answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logon script will run in the current user's context, which will trip UAC. You should use Group Policy Preferences Registry Settings *or* a Startup Script, which will run as `SYSTEM` instead.

The GPP way is "preferred" in most cases.

Comment: You're right i used GPO following this tutorial: http://www.petri.co.il/setting-up-logon-script-through-gpo-windows-server-2008.htm  and everything run smooth on test :)

Thank you